# Using AbsoluteLayout on Android?

Tags: android, simulator, absolutelayout, screen-size

All pages of my application use the AbsoluteLayout which is deprecated.
I was told that the reason i should not use absolutelayout is that it's not flexible in different screen sizes.

I tested my app with every simulator comes with android sdk, and I had no problem.
But all screens on all simulators seem to have the same size.
am i safe to go with absolute layout as long as it works on all simulators?
1.1, 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.2, 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set screen size when creating AVD (by changing Skin Default HVGA to some other). 
And you can also change orientation pressing 7 and 9 keys on numeric keyboard.

Comment: Yeah definitely test with hvga, qvga, and wvga to see the effect of scaling on your UI.

Comment: I don't want my app to run in different orientation, I only want it to run in landscape , 1 side.
Is it possible to force this?
Thank for the answer by the way i'm going to try different screen sizes

Comment: To force landscape put android:screenOrientation="landscape" as attribute of Activity into AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

If all screens on all simulators seem to have the same sizem it's because you are not changing it's resolution at the moment of create them. See Gawcio's response.

> am i safe to go with absolute layout
>   as long as it works on all simulators?

No, you are not. You must stop using `AbsoluteLayout`... there are better ways to build your application.

Comment: The official replacement for `AbsoluteLayout` is to write your own layout manager class that implements your rules.

Comment: Or RelativLayout with use of margins.

Comment: "You can achieve much the same layout by using a FrameLayout  instead, and setting layout_margin attributes of the children. This approach is more flexible and will yield better results on different screens."